# Update locale in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to set timezone in JavaScript. I am using Jajali calendar for date and time but my requirement is that using the iran time zone but default is showing UTC hours.

```
var hrs = cal.date.getUTCHours();
var mins = cal.date.getUTCMinutes();
```

Please advice.

Comment: `getTimezoneOffset()`?

Comment: Well, maybe you would get the local hourse and minutes not the UTC ones?

Comment: No, you cannot update the timezone in which the client is located.

Comment: So your question is why `getUTCHours` is returning UTC time?

Comment: i want to set iran timezone